# If there is a way to create an antigravitational chamber how would it be created?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, acoustics, vacuum

First off, physics is not my major rather it is a hobby that I have gained basic knowledge of over the years. Private research has led me to a hypothetical question: If an electromagnetic device was placed within a vacuum chamber that was reduced to 0 Psi, and acoustic levitation was used to push said magnet, could this not only produce an electromagnetic field around the entire device but also generate enough electric currents to power a the device?

I am open to any information regarding Electromagnetism, Anti-Gravity, Acoustic levitation, and any further guidance I could receive to produce some answers.

Comment: Acoustic levitation relies on there being an atmosphere present for the sound waves to travel through, so it wouldn't work in a vacuum chamber. The way we would transmit power through a vacuum would usually be some form of wireless charging.

Comment: So would it be more likely to make a chamber that is close to 0 in order to provide the least amount of possible resistance on the magnetic device? If the magnet was producing electricity through a movement powered motor much like a wind turbine which in turn powers the acoustic devices, would that be counteractive or could there be an exponential growth in power?

Comment: It sounds as if you're considering some kind of perpetual motion device i.e. your device in the vacuum produces more power than it consumes. If so then this is impossible since energy is always conserved so it cannot be produced from nothing.

Comment: Alright, it was worth a shot. Thank you very much for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what at all you are even asking for. It seems at one point you are asking for anti-gravity, then another electric charge, then another using sonic (acoustic) effects. So given I'm not sure what you're imagining, I will suggest the following:

- Creating antigravity: There is *theoretically* such a thing as "antigravity", i.e. gravity of opposite polarity, but it requires negative mass. If you had some, negative mass would, in effect, "push" positive mass away from it. However, there do not appear to exist negative-mass particles in our Universe, so there is no way to create this. It seems to be one of those things that is compatible with existing physics but just doesn't *actually* exist.
- Electric power in a vacuum chamber: This is not impossible - if you suffuse the vacuum chamber with suitable electromagnetic fields and the device in question is capable of coupling to them, you can transfer power to it wirelessly. However, wireless transmission of power like this is problematic for transmitting large quantities of power. Nikola Tesla wanted to try and do this around the turn of the 19th to the 20th century, but over large scales you pretty much need a focused beam, otherwise you waste virtually all the power.
- Acoustic levitation: This is also a real thing, but it requires air to be present, or some other fluidic medium to conduct the sound. It will not work in a vacuum.

That said, if the aim is simply to levitate an object in a vacuum, then you can definitely do that with *magnetic* fields. The trick is you will need a magnetic track and suitable materials for the object. One famous trick is when you use a superconducting material (so has to be chilled to cryogenic temperature), and place it above a suitably powerful magnet. An effect called the *Meissner effect* will cause the object to hover or float above the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

In the universe we happen to inhabit, gravity is always attractive and therefore antigravity, or the ability to "turn off" gravity somehow, does not exist and cannot be made to exist.

The experiment you propose would be identical to a setup floating in outer space without a vacuum chamber and without the need of antigravity. An electromagnetic device situated there would not generate any electric current in and of itself unless it had some sort of power source inside it- so the answer is "NO".

Comment: I may be confused but if the universe must always stay constant, and there is a gravity then shouldn't anti-gravity be theoretically possible? Much like the experiments conducted by CERN with the use of matter and Anti-matter, there should exist a similar but opposite counterpart to every force, energy, and matter in the universe.

Comment: Nope. Gravity is mediated by *gravitons* with spin = 2, which means gravity is always attractive.